# fancybox v2: How to change the position of title in the DOM?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How could I set the titles of the fancybox-images into another DOM-element. I don't want to use it inside `#fancybox-wrap`. I played with the following codeline 1246 of `jquery.fancybox.js`

`title = $('<div class="fancybox-title fancybox-title-' + opts.type + '-wrap">' + text + '</div>').appendTo('body');`

no results by changing `.appendTo('body');` ?

I just want to use the output of the title in another `div`. Do you have some suggestions?
Thank you - S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try this whenever you launch the fancybox.

```
$('#fancybox-wrap .fancybox-title').appendTo('anotherDomSelector');
```

Comment: beforeShow: function() {
 $('#fancybox-wrap .fancybox-title').appendTo('#hier');
}
No - doesn't work.

Comment: Can you check `alert($('#fancybox-wrap .fancybox-title').length)` inside `beforeShow` handler?

Comment: Your selector is wrong and I see that there is no element with id `fancybox-wrap` on the link your just provided.

Comment: THANK YOU for the support - now it works with:
`onUpdate: function() {$('.fancybox-title').appendTo('#hier');}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in afterShow callback (fancybox 2):

```
afterShow: function(){

    var iframe = this.inner.children(document).contents();
    var body = iframe.find('body');
    var iframeTitle = this.title;

    body.find('.your-container-div').append('<h1>'+iframeTitle+'</h1>');
    console.log(iframeTitle);
},
```